# Real time audio effects on streaming playback

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio

I'm developing audio streaming playback with audio effects such as distortion and reverb on ios.
In my understanding, Audio Unit can add these audio effects.
But, I could not find the way to apply them on streaming playback.

The image I would like to achieve is following...

1. Audio Queue Service receives and stores audio data as streaming data.
2. Audio Queue gives this data to Audio Unit or Audio Graph.
3. Audio Unit adds effects and plays it back in real time.

Do you think I can achieve this design image ?

Comment: When you say streaming playback.  Are you referring to audio being streamed from the network?

Answer (score 2):

The Audio Queue API adds too much latency to do pseudo-real-time audio effects processing.  If you use the Audio Unit API for recording input with very short buffers (6 milliseconds or less on newer iOS devices), your total Audio Graph latency might be tolerable.